# SQL Selecting LIKE results and exact results with replace()

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Sorry if the title isn't very descriptive, I didn't really know how to word this briefly. On my site I have a database table full of video game & eSports Teams. When I display the Team name in a URL, I remove all whitespace from it. For this reason, I need to accept a spaceless version of the name while searching in case someone tries typing in a name that they found in a URL.

Example of a team name: Los Santos Kings

Example of a URL : mysite.com/teams/LosSantosKings

Example Search Query #1 : "Los San" (without quotes)

Example Search Results #1 : Los Santos Kings

Example Search Query #2 : "LosSan" (without quotes)

Example Search Results #1 : empty - 0 rows returned

If you search "Los San" then it returns the Team's database row. However, if you search "LosSan" it does not. This method of using SQL's `replace()` function works fine when I'm testing it for exact matches, but when set next to a LIKE query it doesn't work in the latter instance.

Here is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE name LIKE '%{$search}%' OR replace(name, ' ', '') LIKE '%{".str_replace(' ', '', $search)."}%' ORDER BY name ASC"
```

Is this a syntax error, or do I need to go about this in another way with possibly 2 separate queries/checks for the Team name?

Comment: "Is this a syntax error", did it give you a error?

Comment: No, it gives me no error. Which is why I'm asking here. What I meant by syntax is whether a LIKE and an = statement are allowed in the same query.

Comment: You can use as many `LIKE` and `=` in combination as you want, as long as the logic is correct.  But in your logic, you are using the `replace` function on the column name.  Surely you know the column name at the time of your query?

Comment: Are you familiar with mysql replace()? It doesn't replace content in the column name, it replaces content in the column value. Thanks anyway, I guess? You tried, sort of.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  I see no problem with the way your query is written; it should give you what you are looking for.  However, you really don't need the first `name LIKE '%{$search}%'`, because if it passes everything after your `OR`, it should also pass the first part (that is, it is redundant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LIKE` isn't the problem. It's the curly brackets. When you've written `{$search}` it's because you've injected a PHP variable into the string. But for the `str_replace` you're breaking the string anyway, so you shouldn't bracket it.

Here's your new line:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE name LIKE '%{$search}%' OR replace(name, ' ', '') LIKE '%".str_replace(' ', '', $search)."%' ORDER BY name ASC"
```

Comment: Thank you! Will select your answer as correct when it allows.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need curly braces on the second one.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE name LIKE '%{$search}%' OR replace(name, ' ', '') LIKE '%".str_replace(' ', '', $search)."%' ORDER BY name ASC";
```